# React: Call function conditionally and only once

Tags: reactjs

I want to call the function chooseRandomRestaurant after my data is fetched exactly once.

My data is fetched in another component so i cannot await it.

I tried to wrap it inside a useEffect, somehow like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  dataFetched ? chooseRandomRestaurants(4) :  <div>Loading...</div>;
},[dataFetched])
```

but useEffect doesn't work conditionals. I don't know how to approach it. Could anyone help me?

Comment: "`useEffect` doesn't work conditionals"? `useEffect` can't be **called** conditionally; that's not what's happening here.

Comment: useEffect is for running side-effects, not for rendering UI components.